# KnockoutJS Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, observable

Please checkout this JS Bin
http://jsbin.com/iqikuf/3/edit

When the below is run in the console, the result shown makes sense to me.

> statement: vd.tools.push(dataItem); 
>  resuelt: 2

But why do we get the below result when run in the console?

> statement: vd.tools.length 
>  result: 0

Comment: [vd.tools().length](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#reading_information_from_an_observablearray)

Comment: Thanks DCoder, I can't accept your answer because it's a comment.  Post it as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DCoder pointed out

parentheses needed

vd.tools().length

Answer (score 1):

I would like to integrate and explain DCoder's answer.

`vd.tools` refer to an *observableArray* which is a Javascript object which `length`property does not refer to the amount of stored items.

By "adding the parenthesis" `vd.tools()` we **get a reference to the *underlying array*** which is wrapped by the KnockoutJS's observableArray.

This is the real array which store our data and here we can ask for the `length` property expecting the correct result.

So then DCoder's answer make perfect sense.

Comment: The `.length` on the `tools` observableArray is actually [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), which returns the number of arguments the function is expecting, hence 0.